# Are there any good CIFS proxy out there?

Tags: windows, proxy, samba, cache, cifs

I know samba4 can do this, but apparently it's still in alpha.  I want to have a caching CIFS proxy.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This may be more appropriate on serverfault.